# Find what package a file belongs to in Ubuntu/Debian?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, package-management, dpkg, aptitude

I frequently find myself missing a program, man page, or other file when working on my Ubuntu 8.04 system. Is there any simple way to look up what package contains a given file (whether it is installed already or not)? Maybe some obscure option for apt or dpkg?

Comment: Same on Ubuntu: http://askubuntu.com/questions/481/how-do-i-find-the-package-that-provides-a-file

Comment: **`dpkg -S /path/to/file`** if you have the package installed.

Comment: ^ Accepted answer, better than depending on `apt-file`

Answer (score 320, accepted):

```
apt-file search filename
```

**or**

```
apt-file search /path/to/file
```

To install [`apt-file`](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=apt-file), use:

```
sudo apt-get install apt-file
```

You will need to update its database before you can use it:

```
sudo apt-file update
```

Comment: FYI: apt-file seems to depend on Contents-amd64.gz provided by repositories. And not all 3rd party repos provide this file.

Comment: It did not work for me. I updated the database but it does not return anything. `dpkg -S` works as described below.

Comment: In most cases you will not need to install a non-standard package (apt-file) and get away with using the pre-installed one (dpkg). See top voted answer.

Answer (score 544):

[(Debian/Ubuntu) Discover what package a file belongs to](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/1947/debianubuntu-discover-what-package-a-file-belongs-to):

```
dpkg -S /usr/bin/ls
```

> 'dpkg -S' just matches the string you
>   supply it, so just using 'ls' as an
>   argument matches any file from any
>   package that has 'ls' anywhere in the
>   filename. So usually it's a good idea
>   to use an absolute path. You can see
>   in the second example that 12 thousand
>   files that are known to dpkg match the
>   bare string 'ls'.

Comment: That is only if the files already installed

Comment: In contrast to `apt-file`, this also finds the package to a file if it was installed manually via `dpkg -i`!

Comment: If you get _dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern_ [try this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159001/how-to-find-the-package-that-installed-a-comand-if-dpkg-s-finds-no-path-beca/159002#159002): `dpkg -S "$(readlink -fn "$(which rename)")"`.

Comment: Weird, this didn't work for me: `dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /usr/bin/java`, though there is a file at `/usr/bin/java`

Comment: @nnyby See comment of Pablo A

Comment: @Vog That solution doesn't work in my case.

Comment: @nnyby Which OS and version are you using? On Debian 10 (buster) the command `dpkg -S "$(readlink -fn "$(which java)")"` returns `openjdk-11-jre-headless:amd64: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java`

Answer (score 24):

[packages.debian.org](http://packages.debian.org) is what I always use to accomplish this task.  It is superior over apt-file because it can find parts of filenames as well.  It's also linked up to the main packages list which will list descriptions, bugs, etc.  All in all a good website.  Not as useful from the command line, but still quite useful.

For speed, I bookmarked the url:

```
http://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=%s&mode=filename&suite=unstable&arch=any
```

in Firefox, and added "debfind" as a keyword (click "more" in the bookmark manager with it hilighted), so I can just type "debfind " and it will work.  You can change 'suite' it from unstable to stable or testing if you like, for other versions of the distribution.

Comment: It doesn't work with custom repos though.

Comment: Poor choice in regards to automation.

Answer (score 12):

You can also use dlocate. From the man page;

```
$ dlocate [ PATTERN ]
List all records where either the package name or the filename matches PATTERN.
```

Comment: `dlocate` is also my favorite method, very reliable.

Comment: @Avio `dlocate` does not find a recently installed package unless you run `sudo update-dlocatedb` first. The command is automatically run daily in /etc/cron.daily/dlocate

Answer (score 5):

I found Wajig...

```
wajig whichpackage /path/to/file
```

eg.

```
wajig whichpackage /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Wajig is a handy command line or  console tool which wraps all the apt-get, dpkg goodness that you never wanted to learn.  .

To install wajig use:

```
apt-get install wajig
```

That command 'whichpackage' itself depends on apt-file

you will still need to update its database before you can use it: - I don't know yet if wajig update whixh  does an apt-get update also updates the file cache, but I expect it may.

```
sudo wajig update

sudo apt-file update
```

( and Super Cow, Easter egss ? ! )

Answer (score 3):

Simmilar to jamuraa's answer for Debian, you can also go to http://packages.ubuntu.com/ for Ubuntu. You'll have to scroll down a bit to find the *"Search the contents of packages"* searchbox where you can enter the path of a file.

Comment: Now if only Raspbian also had one :)

Answer (score 0):

The command-not-found package gives you hints about potential commands and the name of the debian package. It works by typing the command in the bash shell and looking at its output.

For example if the command name is known:

```
zer@ivy:~ 10:45 $ zsh5
The program 'zsh5' is currently not installed.  To run 'zsh5' please ask
your administrator to install the package 'zsh'
zsh5: command not found
```

and if the command is not known, some guesses are applied:

```
zer@ivy:~ 09:46 $ zsh
No command 'zsh' found, did you mean:
 Command 'lsh' from package 'lsh-client' (main)
 Command 'osh' from package 'omake' (main)
 Command 'ysh' from package 'libyaml-shell-perl' (main)
 Command 'ssh' from package 'openssh-client' (main)
 Command 'vsh' from package 'crystalspace' (main)
 Command 'dsh' from package 'dsh' (main)
 Command 'ash' from package 'ash' (main)
 Command 'msh' from package 'nmh' (main)
 Command 'zssh' from package 'zssh' (main)
 Command 'qsh' from package 'gridengine-client' (main)
 Command 'sh' from package 'dash' (main)
 Command 'bsh' from package 'bsh' (main)
zsh: command not found
```

Comment: This does not work for arbitrary files however, like the OP requested.

Comment: This is a problematic tip if the program does harmful things and IS installed. Adding `-h` or `--help` at the end would help a bit. If adding `-h` at the end would make this safe enough I would recommend, but even so it is not a good way to achieve what the OP asks.